# sorting objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone

My NSMutableArray contain the list of GroupUser objects :

```
@interface GroupUser : NSObject {

    NSString *groupUser_name;//user name
    NSString *groupUser_customMsg;
    NSString *groupUser_emailId;
    NSString *groupUser_groupName;
    NSString *groupUser_aliasName;
    int groupUser_imageId;
    int groupUser_state;//whether user is online( value 0) offline(value 1) or busy(value 2)
    int groupUser_type;             
}
```

now i want to sort the list :
1. On the bases of  groupUser_state 
2. On the bases of groupUser_name

eg::  1.   Sam             Offline(value 1)
      2.   Ravi            Online(value 0)
      3.   Amit            Online(value 0)
      4.   Ganga           Online(value 0)
      5.   Durga           Offline(value 1)

Output after sorting should be::
1.  Amit   Online
2.  Ganga  Online
3.  Ravi   Online
4.  Durga  Offline
5.  Sam    Offline

Help me by providing code for the same.. Thanx in advance

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: still if you don't get then click http://bit.ly/LQlR4Z

Comment: i have tried sorting by name(using sortedArrayUsingComparator) and its done ... but i want to sort it by state first and then by the name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSSortDescriptor *desc=[NSSortDescriptor  sortDescriptorWithKey:@"groupUser_state" ascending:YES];
NSArray *yourArray;
[yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:desc]];
```

Comment: Thanx every one who answered. With help of all links i got my solution

NSArray *sortedArray;

NSSortDescriptor* stateDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"groupUser_state" ascending:NO] autorelease];

NSSortDescriptor* nameDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"groupUser_name" ascending:YES] autorelease];

NSArray* sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stateDescriptor, nameDescriptor, nil];

sortedArray = [[m_appDelegate groupUsersList] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]; 
Feel free to comment on this solution .. if in any sense i can improve it

Comment: @Saraswati When adding code like this, it is a good idea to edit your original question and add the solution to the end or add your own answer so that people can actually read it.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can call NSMutableArray's -sortUsingSelector:, but your custom objects should provide a method for making the comparisons, something like this:

```
- (NSComparisonResult) compareSomeVariable:(GroupUser*) otherUser
{
    // Assumes ivar _someVariable is numeric; use NSString methods to compare
    // strings, etc.

    if(this->_someVariable < otherObject->_someVariable){
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if(this->_someVariable > otherObject->_someVariable){
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else{
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

and the sort them like this:

```
[array sortUsingSelector:@selector(compareSomeVariable:)];
```

The drawback is that you have to define this custom method in your class.
You can have several different methods to sort your objects according to different criteria.